# SQL to find out notification sent in last n mins

Tags: sql

We have a notification log table having 2 columns-
email address
notification_sent_time

I need to find out the number of notifications sent to a particular email address in last 'n' seconds. How to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can we see some code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE email_address = {email} AND notification_sent_time > {N seconds ago}`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the datediff function.

```
WHERE email_address = {email} and DATEDIFF('ss', notification_sent_time, GETDATE()) > 2
```